# Why can't I open an external application as MDI?

Tags: c#, mdi

When I open an external application as MDI Child, the application opens, but not as an MDI child. I have a class that runs notepad.exe correctly, but it doesn't work with my own application:

```
public class ExternalApp {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
    public static void LoadProcessInControl(string app_path, Control parent) {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(app_path);
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        ExternalApp.SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, parent.Handle);
    }
}
```

I call the function with this:

```
ExternalApp.LoadProcessInControl(@"C:\Users\Bálint\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TesztApp\TesztApp.exe", this);
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the Notepad window is not of the proper style (it's not a MDI child window, it's a top-level window). You can't force a window to be something it isn't, any more than you can force your goldfish to be a packmule just by strapping large, heavy packages to his back.

Comment: @mbalint987 I basically have the same as you, with Notepad.exe as the app to load it works and notepad appears as a child - great, but I have another application which I created (not notepad or calc) and that just loads up as normal, but not as a child - did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was mistaken in my comment those properties don't need to be set.  It's been awhile. :)  To do this I've had some success using a panel inside a child form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForInputIdle();
        SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
        //This maximizes the process window. 
        SendMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0);
        return;
    }
}
```

The documentation for SendMessage is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx).
The child form is shown like this, with Notepad embedded:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form2 newForm2 = new Form2();
    newForm2.MdiParent = this;
    newForm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: How can you get this parameters? 274, 61488, 0

Comment: @mbalint987 - I added a link to the documentation page for SendMessage.